# Search by data attribute, and replace

Tags: jquery, html

This is my HTML

```
<a href="#" data-finder-code="" data-dropdown-placeholder="Select..." data-dropdown-text="1">Samsung</a>
```

And this is my JQuery

```
var finder_code = 39;
$("a[data-dropdown-text='1']").data("finder-code", finder_code);
```

When i search by `$("a[data-dropdown-text='1']")` and try to replace the `data-finder-code` in the same `href` nothing happens. How do i get this to work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is working fine. When you use `data()` jQuery only updates its internal cache for performance reasons. If you retrieve the value using the getter of `data()`, then you can see it's working fine:

```js
var finder_code = 39;
$("a[data-dropdown-text='1']").data("finder-code", finder_code);

console.log($("a[data-dropdown-text='1']").data('finder-code'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-finder-code="" data-dropdown-placeholder="Select..." data-dropdown-text="1">Samsung</a>
```

If you *have* to update the value in the DOM, then you can use `attr('data-finder-code')`, however it will be marginally slower:

```
var finder_code = 39;
$("a[data-dropdown-text='1']").attr('data-finder-code', finder_code);
```

Comment: Thanks! didn't know you had to use `attr()` to update DOM. thought `data()` would do the same thing. thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses internal cache to persist arbitrary data when using `.data(key, value)` it won't update the DOM.

Otherwise your code will work. However If you want to update the attribute value use `.attr(key, value)`

```
$("a[data-dropdown-text='1']").attr("data-finder-code", finder_code);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var finder_code = 39;
$("a[data-dropdown-text='1']").attr("data-finder-code", finder_code);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" data-finder-code="" data-dropdown-placeholder="Select..." data-dropdown-text="1">Samsung</a>
```

Please try replacing `data("finder-code")` with `attr("data-finder-code")` for DOM updates.